# Identifying which Hive job created temporary files

Tags: mapreduce, hive

Assuming I have names of temporary files from Hive job and at a given time multiple jobs were executing, is it possible to identify which Hive job produced chosen files? Is it logged somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about running and past jobs  is available in `http://jobtrackerhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp.`

Going into link with job details there is also link to Job File which shows information about names of files used in hdfs `/tmp/hive-${username}` `mapred.cache.files`.

This information is also available in xml files in `$HADOOP_HOME/mr1/logs/`  files: `*conf.xml`